Laptop WiFi becomes slow when the lid is closed
I have Ubuntu Server 24.04 on my laptop but I am experiencing a problem: the WiFi on my laptop degrades when I close the lid.
First of all, I edited the /etc/systemd/logind.conf to handle the lid triggers:
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no

Furthermore, I disabled any WiFi power saving capability
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off

but doing that did not help. The moment I close the lid, the WiFi card abruptly stops working as expected, but other parts of the computer, including cable ethernet connection and CPU performance remain the same.
Here an image of a local speedtest. The moment I open the lid is shown by a red mark.

This is the output of sudo iwconfig when the lid is open:
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"xxx"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:33  Invalid misc:200   Missed beacon:0

This is the output of sudo iwconfig when the lid is closed:
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"xxx"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:33  Invalid misc:200   Missed beacon:0

As you can see, link quality and signal level degrades when I close the lid. So I thought: "the position of the lid when it's closed interferes with the radio signal of the WiFi card". I tried to confirm or reject this hypothesis by moving the laptop in several ways and simulating interference when the lid is open, but it still works fine in these conditions.
Is there anything I am missing?

I am sorry. I meant 24.04.
